# unable to see classes in my django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-models

i created 2 classes in my models.py which i can access through shell but cant see it on my /admin page.
i used python manage.py migrate and makemigrations

my models.py:

```
    from django.db import models
    
    
    class Company(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    
    class Product:
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
```

my admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from.models import Company, Product

admin.register(Company)
admin.register(Product)
```

thanks

Comment: it is admin.site.register()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your admin.py to this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Company, Product

admin.site.register(Company)
admin.site.register(Product)
```